# CruiseControl.net continuously sends error messages whenever it can't connect to SVN

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

And this is pretty annoying since we have it set up to continuously check svn every 20 seconds. So if svn is down for some reason we could potentially be getting 3 error emails every minute.

For example, svn was down today and I had about 90 emails from CruiseControl.net on how it can't connect to svn in my inbox when I came in the morning (cruisecontrol starts at 8:30am and I come in at 9:00am, 3 errors per minute, so 3*30=90 messages).

Mind you, the notificationType for emails I have set up in cruisecontrol is "Change". But I guess this only pertains to builds and not actually checking svn.

Now don't get me wrong, I'd like to know when there's a problem connecting to SVN but 1 email would be nice and not a zillion.

Any ideas? thanks in advance..

Comment: ... 90 messages? Lucky you! Last week I received more than 40,000 mails from our CCNET server over night...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by setting

'ReportOnRetryAmount' in sourceControlErrorHandling

Answer (score 1):

You should check for similar Q/A which has already been answered: [Can we tell CruiseControl.NET to ignore source control timeout errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086957/can-we-tell-cruisecontrol-net-to-ignore-source-control-timeout-errors)