# Why does failed source control in CruiseControl.net not fail the build?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm using cruisecontrol.net for integration builds along with external source control. The source control (GETMODS) script fails, this is fine and I know why, but the build stays green for some reason when it's expected to fail. CruiseControl shows the exception on the output window below, so why doesn't the build fail?

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed:

at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute
(ProcessInfo processInfo)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.GetModifications(ProcessInfo info, DateTime from, DateTime to)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ExternalSourceControl.GetMod  ifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResultthisBuild)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Project.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.ProjectIntegrator.Integrate()
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.ProjectIntegrator.Run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reasoning would be that the source control block is only used:

- to check if there are any changes in the source code which require a rebuild, and
- to get all the source code needed for the build.

If this action fails it has nothing to do with the source code and the commits to it. It's an infrastructural problem that prevents the build from happening at all therefore technically the build hasn't fails. It hasn't even started.

Answer (score 0):

With a version control block inside cc.net, it search for repository modification.
If cc.net is unable to contact the repository, it can't start the job.
The result is an **exception**.

If you want to ignore this, this can help (simple retry counter) !

[Can we tell CruiseControl.NET to ignore source control timeout errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086957/can-we-tell-cruisecontrol-net-to-ignore-source-control-timeout-errors/2086994#2086994)

```
<maxSourceControlRetries>5</maxSourceControlRetries>
<stopProjectOnReachingMaxSourceControlRetries>true</stopProjectOnReachingMaxSourceControlRetries>
<sourceControlErrorHandling>ReportOnRetryAmount</sourceControlErrorHandling>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not about ignoring the exception though ... I want it to fail the build or otherwise make it obvious that someone needs to check the logs and fix whatever is causing it. With the exception it's just a text in the window on the server nobody looks at... I tries your suggestion but I think the CCNet version I am using doesn't support that feature in 1.4.0.3308

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a recent change to ccnet. We are running two versions on separate machines. Version 1.4 breaks the build if it can't get to our svn repository, but version 1.5 will not break the build.  I haven't looked into it yet, but there may be a switch to force 1.5 to break on failure to retrieve code.