# Ignore SVN errors with CruiseControl.Net

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

We have recently configured CruiseControl.Net on a not-very-much-used server. Our SVN server is another one.
Our SVN server restarts nearly every night to install updates.
Unfortunately, this restart is breaking the CruiseControl build, and it's getting annoying.

Is it possible to not break the build when the CruiseControl.Net trigger fails ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`<filterTrigger>`](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Filter+Trigger) to prevent repository access during the time it is not available.

Comment: It will do. I also found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086957/can-we-tell-cruisecontrol-net-to-ignore-source-control-timeout-errors ; thanks !